# Can't install msys2 in windows7 with latest updates

Tags: windows-7, msys2

I had previously installed msys2 on Win7. After installing latest updates on Win7, the bash that comes with msys2 did not work any more. I removed msys2 and tried reinstalling it (the latest 64bit version form msys2.org).

The installation process stops at 66%. On details, it shows installing C:\msys64\usr\share\terminfo\6e\nansi.sys and it won't move forward.

In the task manager it shows several bash.exe processes. If I kill these processe, the installation ask if I want to try again? If I agree, a new bash.exe process appears and nothing happens. The installation won't move forward.

Can anyone tell me where the problem might be?